# How do I check that my app is iOS7 compatible according to Apple Standards?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

[According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/news/):

> Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App
>   Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be
>   optimized for iOS 7.

How do I check that my iOS app conforms to these requirements ? Is there a checklist somewhere ? If I do not get any warnings when uploading to AppStore today, can I assume there won't be any problems by February ?

I believe my app is 'optimized for iOS7', but Apple only refers to their Human Interface Guidelines, where I think some of the requirements are subjective.

I should mention that I think I have all the basics covered - using SDK7 and XCode 5, got all the new icon sizes, etc.

Comment: I would probably read that: "..and must be built with a base SDK of 7.x"

Comment: My main concern would be: does it need to be compiled with iOS SDK 7.0? At this moment I am using XCode 5 together with iOS 6 SDK. My apps are transitioned visually to iOS 7, but some of them are just legacy code which will mean a major pain to transition to iOS 7 SDK.

Comment: @Esteban, I am pretty sure that you do need to use iOS7 SDK.

Comment: You will need to use the iOS 7 SDK. Using the iOS 6 SDK with Xcode 5 requires modifying the app bundle and isn't supported by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

The [iOS 7 transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/) is a good place to start. After that, all your app submissions must be compiled against the iOS 7 SDK, using Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

You won't experience any problems if you upload your app today and it passes the review. The news states that optimization for iOS7 is obligatory for *new* apps and *updates*. However, you can make life easier if your app meets the requirements (see previous answer and the comment below your question) right now.

Comment: What I am worried about is not being able to update an existing app after February 1st.